# Visual Studio's Intellisense is faulty: CS0234 The type or namespace name <name> does not exist in the namespace <namespace>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on a repository that I've had no problem with it until recently. None of my colleagues are having problems on their machines either, so I'm led to believe this is a problem with my Visual Studio.

I keep getting hundreds of errors, as follows:

`Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name <name> does not exist in the namespace <namespace> (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

It's like all of the references are broke. But when I build there are no build errors. Just Intellisense errors.

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Restart Visual Studio, do a build clean, delete the `.vs` folder at the solution root. Does it compile at the command line fine? Like `dotnet build` (assuming it's not an old .NET Framework app)

Comment: Thanks. That's got rid of those errors. Now I have errors: `Error CS0006 Metadata file 'C:\...' could not be found ...`

My build log has this first error: 
`warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Web.Http" that could not be resolved.`

Comment: The metadata one should go away when you build (and maybe restart) That warning, er, not sure, could be conflicts in the Nuget packages, or maybe different version of .NET Framework installed.

Comment: Hero @DavidG. It's working!

Comment: This question is a better fit at SuperUser

Comment: Intellisense information was partliy stored in .vs folder, if you encountered this wired intellisense issue, consider remove the folder and regenerate it via restart the visual studio when you encounter this issue. You can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you encountered is a common issue that may meet.

This situation caused by some intellisense information stored in .vs folder.

Take a look of this:

[Still forced to delete ".vs" folder to fix build errors or IntelliSense errors](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4728)

After you delete/remove the .vs folder and restart the visual studio, the visual studio will regenerate a new .vs folder with the new intellisense information.

By the way, this behavior was not recorded in official documents.

Comment: Thanks for this. Amazing that the same problem has been around for so many years!